# followup on mass converting google docs

Tags: google-docs

This question from apr '14 gives a way to download google docs as word, pdf or other files:

[Migrate Google docs to Office 365, convert from .gdoc to .docx](https://superuser.com/questions/745440/migrate-google-docs-to-office-365-convert-from-gdoc-to-docx)

select the files, click "more", then "download...", and a wizard takes it from there.

Currently under "more" there is no "download..." just "download" which does not start a conversion wizard but immediately generates a .zip with the selected files. In what format you ask? Probably the slimiest thing google could do: no document format, just a link to the online doc. Do folks know if this functionality has been removed? Are there other popular ways to migrate from google docs?